# Javascript if statements in displaying images

Tags: javascript

Hey i am currently trying to get a program running in javascript i want the program to display the 4 images one after each other with the single press of a button and then after the 4 images have cycled through i want them to stop cycling and i cant seem to do it this is my code i currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var images = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"];
var imagenum = 0;
var timer;
function imageCycle()
{
if(++imagenum == 4)
imagenum = 0;


document.image.src = images[imagenum];
timer = setTimeout("imageCycle()",1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.png" name="image" width=800 height=600>

<form>
<input type="button" value="images" name="cycle images"       onclick="imageCycle()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is appreciated many thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout("imageCycle()",1000);` will invoke `eval` from the timeout which in your case will have performance repercussions. Instead use `setTimeout(imageCycle,1000);` - Other than that, your code is too simple, you're incrementing `imagenum` and if it equals `4` you're resetting it to `0`. So self explanatory that I don't know any more what's your real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you continue to schedule the function, that's why the images continue to rotate.

If you want to stop at the forth image displayed, you have to put the setTimeout line in an else statement.

```
if (++imagenum == 4) {
    imagenum = 0;
} else {
    document.image.src = images[imagenum];
    timer = setTimeout("imageCycle()",1000);
}
```

Another point, that other users notice and I just report here in my answer.

You use the string:

*imageCycle()*

as the first argument of setTimeout, insted you should use just the function name.

```
timer = setTimeout(imageCycle, 1000);
```

Comment: Why you use String in setTimeout first argument? Actually why a timer at all. On click = change image. It's totally unclear what's that timeout for.

Comment: I want the program to cycle through all four images and then stop with one button press not pressing the button to change each image individually

Comment: I strictly answer the question here. After that, I agree that the first argument on setTimeout could be, in this case, the function name, instead the string I copied from the code snipped. I suppose the timer is used to delay the image change.

Comment: The timer is used to delay the image change

Comment: I added your code to mine and it works how i wanted it to so thanks alot Mario Alexandro Santini